# Why is this ActiveRecord relationship not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to access the 'groups' or 'members' properties on my Users class, I get an undefined method error for members.  (Note: I know that I need to redefine my members class as singular, that's secondary to figuring out why it's broken to begin with)

I have a user class as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :group, :through => :member
end
```

Members class:

```
class Members < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Groups class:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through => :members
end
```

And a schema that contains:

```
create_table "groups", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "group_name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "members", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "group_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "members", ["group_id"], name: "index_members_on_group_id"
add_index "members", ["user_id"], name: "index_members_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "",     null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",     null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,      null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "role",                   default: "user"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `has_many` for the join model in your `User` and `Group` models.

Add `has_many :members` to both `User` and `Group` model class definition:

***User Model:***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :members
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end
```

Note that in your `User` model you have `has_many :group, :through => :member`.  Since you're defining a `has_many` relationship, your association symbols need to be plural as well.

***Group Model:***

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :members
    has_many :users, :through => :members
end
```

***With `class_name` option*** *if you'd like to keep `Members` class name `Members`(plural):*

Yes, you should consider renaming `Members` model to `Member` as per the convention.  However if you still would like to keep it plural or for that matter any other name, you can specify the `class_name` option in `has_many` declaration such that the symbol to class name are mapped correctly. So, your `User` and `Group` model need to be updated to:

***User Model:***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :members, class_name: 'Members'
  has_many :groups, :through => :members
end
```

***Group Model:***

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :members, class_name: 'Members'
    has_many :users, :through => :members
end
```

Comment: Now that I've gotten the relationship issue worked out, I actually renamed it to 'Membership', with 'Memberships' as the table name.  Thanks for the help, though.